# Tridion: Component template placing within page

Tags: components, tridion

I want get expert advice on how we can place the same Component presentations on different section of the page without creating new Component templates or components.
So the issue we are having is that we have a Component template, and we want the flexibility of placing it in multiple locations on multiple pages because its physical presentation is identical the content is identical.

Is there a way to achieve this without creating 4 different CTs?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmkUB.jpg

Comment: Same content displaying on the single page 4 different places does not make sense from either business requirement or end user point of view. Why would any one want to see the same content on a single page at 4 different places. Are you sure that is your real requirement?

Comment: It wont be the same page, it would the same component and same component template but different location on different pages. Not necessarily the same page.

Comment: You should update your question to clarify that. `placing it in multiple locations on a single page` , this is what confusing in your question.  If it is on different pages you can absolutely do it. You only need to figure out the rules and logic on which section the component will go on each page.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but, in a very generic way, if you want to:

1. Display the same **Component Presentation** on different locations of the *same* page.

   - You can manage it on your **Page Template**
2. Display the same **Component Presentation** in different locations of **different** pages.

   - Simply by using different Page Templates
   - By changing the order of your component presentation. (and managing this on your page template)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible unfortunately, you will need to create different CTs for each section of the page as Tridion doesn't store the location of the CT on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position the same Component Presentation in different locations on different pages then the first thing that pops in to my head is "*Should these be different Page Templates?*".  This would give you the ability to easily control the location of the Component Presentations based on the Component Template used or the Component's Schema.

When you say that they need to be in different places, is this within the same 'content area' (and relative to the other Components) on the page or is it actually in another area of the page?  If it is just relative to the other Components (of that type) on the Page then you could just output these in the order that they are added to the Page in Tridion (probably by creating a TBB that groups all Components of that type in to an array first).

This really depends on what the rules are for where the Components should be positioned and why!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this is the age-old issue of having "widgets" in the LHS/RHS area which have identical HTML output but no way for the PT to know where to place them (other than by a field value in the component or by the name/tcmuri of the CT).

This is essentially a case of having metadata at the component presentation level (doesn't really belong to the component or the CT as the placement can be different for different pages even with the same component and CT).

I've used the following solutions for this problem:

- create 1 CT and copy it 4 times (you will have the exact same DWT, parameter settings etc only the name will be different)
- create 1 CT and "abuse" tridion's targetgroup mechanism (create a target group LHS and a target group RHS and "target" the CT at the locations; in your PT filter the CPs on the selected target group)

The second solution has it's benefits but at a potential cost; what will happen if you in the future want to use Tridion's profiling and personalization? It might not have any consequences but as I have no experience with the combination of the two (the "hack" and what P&P is supposed to be used for) I cannot make any guarantees...